# How to prove fg doesn't equal to gf in permutation?

Tags: permutations

1.Let f ∈ S3 be a permutation which is not the identity. Prove that there exists g ∈ S3
such that fg ≠ gf.

2.Let n ≥ 3, and let f ∈ Sn be a permutation which is not the identity. Prove that
there exists g ∈ Sn such that fg ≠ gf.

Hey guys I am completely stuck in these two questions I'm really not sure where to start with solving it, can anyone please give me a hint? Any helps would be appreciated!

Update: Thanks everyone for giving me hint and helping me with that question. I have attempted to work on the first question and here is what I've got:
Since f ∈ S3 and it is not identity. This can conclude that there would be 5 permutations in f and 6 permutations for g as g ∈ S3.

We then test the permutations by multiple one f permutation to all g permutations. For example we take f = (321) and we multiple it with all g permutations available.
We would then be able to prove fg ≠ gf in most sets except the one where g is identity and the one that g has the same permutation as f.

Then, we can take this set to conclude that fg ≠ gf in f ∈ S3 and f is not identity and g ∈ S3 except when g is identity and the one that g has the same permutation as f.

Would this be correct at all?

Comment: You know, $S_3$ has only five nonidentity elements. You could just try them all. Even easier, if you happen to have the multiplication table for the group in front of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $f$ as a bijective function from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself. Since $f$ is not the identity, we have at least one $k \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $f(k)\ne k$. Let $g \in S_n$ such that $g(k)=k$ and $g(f(k)) \ne f(k)$ (note that we need $n\ge 3$ here. Why?).

Now we have

$f(g(k))=f(k) \ne g(f(k))$

so $f$ and $g$ don't commute.

Answer (score 0):

*Case $n=3$*

This is best treated with disjoint cycle notation.

Consider $(12)$; then $(12)(13)=(132)$ and $(13)(12)=(123)$.

Consider $(123)$; then $(123)(12)=(13)$ and $(12)(123)=(23)$.

Up to a renaming of the elements, these are the only needed cases.

*Case $n\ge3$.*

Suppose $f$ is not the identity. By a renaming of the elements, we can assume that $f(1)=2$. Take the permutation $g$ that exchanges $2$ and $3$ and leaves everything else fixed. Then
$$
g(f(1))=g(2)=3,\qquad f(g(1))=f(1)=2
$$
Therefore $gf\ne fg$.